# SSL termination on AWS ELB for Multiple websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, webserver, amazon-elb

We have an in-house datacenter and we are planning to migrate to AWS.
Almost 500+ websites are running now and most of them are https enabled and we have configured SSL on our f5 Load balancer.Can someone help me to identify the best option to run the the infrastructure on AWS.

My plan was to migrate all website to AWS, Multiple ec2 instance with autoscaling  and run under ELB, but i have read some documentation and came to Know that, ELB can't support multiple SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using EC2 with the Autoscaling is a great choice.

Regarding ELB, the traditional classic load balancer doesn't support Multiple SSL certificates but modern Application Load Balancer does support multiple SSL certificates.

Here is a reference you can go through: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/elastic-load-balancing-application-load-balancers-now-support-multiple-ssl-certificates-and-smart-certificate-selection-using-server-name-indication-sni/